# What's the true regularized value of product of all natural numbers?

Tags: divergent-series, regularization

[Muñoz Garcia and Pérez-Marco - The product over all primes is $4\pi^2$](http://cds.cern.ch/record/630829/files/sis-2003-264.pdf) claims that the regularized value of product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty k$ is $\sqrt{2\pi}$ and of $\prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k$ over primes $p_k$ is $4\pi^2$.

This seems misleading to me because what they in fact calculate is the exponent of the regularized value of the logarithm of the product: $\exp(\operatorname{reg}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \ln a_k)$. I call this thing "[hypermodulus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424664/exponent-of-the-scalar-part-of-the-finite-part-of-the-logarithm-of-an-object-or)", and it is more like determinant as opposed to regularized value which is more like trace (scalar part).

Thus the question arises, what are the true regularized values of these products? In my impression, the regularized value of $\prod_{k=1}^\infty k$ should be equal to the regularized value of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)\Gamma(k)$.

Comment: Surely "the" in "*the* regularized value" is a misnomer; all one can do is to specify a regularisation method and report the result?

Comment: @LSpice regularized value is just the finite part, there cannot be two different values of finite part, like there cannot be two different values of trace of a matrix or real part of a complex number or main value of a function at a pole or the value of Lapolace transform or mean value of a sequence. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4475149/scalar-part-of-algebras-over-a-field-how-natural-is-the-trace-map

Answer (score 2):

[Zeta-regularization of arithmetic sequences](https://www.epj-conferences.org/articles/epjconf/pdf/2020/20/epjconf_cdd2020_01008.pdf) by 
Jean-Paul Allouche (2020) provides a comprehensive discussion.

> Is it possible to give a reasonable value to the infinite
> product $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \cdots \times n \times \cdots$? In
> other words, can we define some sort of convergence of the finite
> product $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \cdots \times n$ when $n$ goes to
> infinity? One way is to relate this product to the Riemann zeta
> function and to its analytic continuation. This approach leads to: $1
> \times 2 \times 3 \times \cdots \times n \times \cdots = \sqrt{2\pi}$.
> More generally, the "zeta-regularisation" of an infinite product
> consists of introducing a related Dirichlet series and its analytic
> continuation at 0 (if it exists). We will survey some properties of
> this generalized product and allude to applications.

Comment: This is the same as in the linked paper. They take the logrithm of the product, find regularized sum of the series, then exponentiate, this is definitely, wrong.

Comment: By what rule they consider the regularized value of the exponent to be equal to the exponent of the regularized value? It is like considering real part of exponent to be equal to the exponent of the real part.

Comment: One simple example where their method gives a wrong value is $\prod_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k$. It is obvious that the regularized value of this product is $0$ (because it is the average of the product at infinity), while their method will give $i$.

Answer (score 0):

The command of Mathematica 13.1

```
Product[j, {j, 2, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

produces $\sqrt{2 \pi }$. In fact, MMA finds the sum of the series of $\log k$, making use of [analytic continuation of Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series).

Comment: I'd like to add that `Product[7 + (j + 3), {j, 1, Infinity}, 
  Regularization -> "Dirichlet"] // FullSimplify` results in $e^{-\zeta ^{(1,0)}(0,11)}$.

Comment: Then, this is a subject to bug report.